# Prüfer sequence for an order-2 tree?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

All the algorithms for constructing a Prüfer sequence state that the input is a tree, but none give any output corresponding to an order-2 tree.

And Wikipedia gives this definition:" A Prüfer sequence of a labeled tree is a unique sequence associated with the tree." Then it adds, "The sequence for a tree on n vertices has length n − 2."

Okay, am I correct to understand then that the Prüfer sequence of a tree with exactly two vertices is the empty sequence, then the Prüfer sequence for a trivial tree is undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a Prüfer sequence to reconstitute a tree, you have to have the set of labeled vertices. If there are one or two vertices only, then the tree is apparent. So with so few vertices, the empty sequence does indeed uniquely reconstitute the tree.

In other words, "uniqueness" applies among all trees of the same size vertex set. Most of the time, uniqueness extends across different sized vertex sets just by virtue of different length Prüfer codes.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. By the way, does "labeled" in graph theory/combinatorics generally understood to mean labeled "1,2,3,4,5,..." (as opposed to, say, "0,2,3,9,77,88,...") ?

Comment: The labels could theoretically come from any set of size $n$. Of course, these need to be the same labels that you have in the Prüfer sequence. And the Prüfer sequence doesn't show you all of the labels. So for the sake of everyone knowing what each other is talking about, it helps to make the labels come from $\{1,\ldots n\}$.

Comment: Yes, I understand the reasoning. I was wondering if "labeled" (if given no further information) in combinatorics/graphTheory generally means "labeled with the sequence of natural numbers starting from 1"..

Comment: I wouldn't think that it would always have to mean that. For instance I might label vertices that represent people with their actual names. However I'd have an ordering in mind (alphabetical?) and always be prepared to identify each label with a number in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ using that order.